# Create CSV file to read from Internet

Tags: csv, file, flutter, dart

How to create CSV file with an opportunity to read it from URL? For example: http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv

Comment: CSV are nothing more than text files where the fields are separated by commas. Just create and place on a server.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the **csv** package. Add csv dependency to your pubspec.yaml file

```
csv: ^4.0.3  
http:
```

```
import 'package:csv/csv.dart' as csv;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<List>> csvToList() async {
    var csvfile= await http.get('url');
    csv.CsvToListConverter converter= new csv.CsvToListConverter(
      eol: '\r\n', fieldDelimiter: ','
    );
    List<List> listCreated= converter.convert(csvfile.body); // the csv file is converted to a 2-Dimensional list
      return listCreated;

  }
```

The csv object also provides a method that can be used to create a csv file from a list of lists:

```
csv.ListToCsvConverter(List<List<dynamic>> input) //accepts a List of Lists as input
```